# Conditional Format based on column header

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a list of products in Column A, csv lists of attributes in column B, then a column for each unique attribute across the sheet to column BI.

I want to highlight the cells in each column, that appear in the csv for that row. I'll try and explain with this example:

```
ColumnA          ColumnB          ColumnC     ColumnD      ColumnE     etc...
Products         csv List        Attribute1  Attribute2   Attribute3   etc...
Product1  Attribute1,Attribute3  (Formatted)   (blank)    (Formatted), etc...
Product2  Attribute2,Attribute3    (blank)   (Formatted)  (Formatted), etc...
```

So, if the column name appears in the respective row's csv, then format the cell.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the conditional formatting by formula, set the range (in this case) to `$C$2:$E$3` and the formula to `=SEARCH(C$1, $B2)` 
The relative reference will do the rest by adjusting the search term and lookup range automatically

Comment: OK, that works kind of. It highlights the cell above the expected one in the column.

Comment: Are you sure? It works exactly as specified by you for me. Do you have this layout? http://imgur.com/JximAo2

Comment: Yes, exact layout, but I get this: http://screencast.com/t/05MjzifsfLk  sorry I can't get imgur at work.

Comment: I looks like you applied the rule to $C$1:$F$3 instead of $C$2:$F$4

Comment: Duh! Hey, well spotted, kudos to you for that. OK, all working perfectly now. Many thanks, all.