# column conditional formatting based on header value

Tags: excel

I have the following table

[image]

Based on the date value in the column header, i want to color the entire column.
If cell=Today(), color the entire column below.

Comment: [Why not images of Code and Sample Data](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/285557#285557) and [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812).

Comment: So you've gone through [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f). What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: I'm having trouble applying the formula across the table. In the image i have posted, the column to be highlighted changes daily when i use the formula=Today(). As of now, this applies to only a single column. How can I apply this formula on all the columns of the table.

Comment: Select A:Z then use `=A$1=today()`

Comment: Thanks Jeeped. Using A$1 instead of $A$1 worked. Here's the formula i used - =G$7:AJ$7=TODAY(), Applies to =$G$7:$AH$16(Formats the entire column.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33223329/conditional-format-based-on-column-header

Answer (score 3):

one approach using Conditional Formatting would be to highlight (select) the column of information you want to colour.  Then with top cell of highlighted column selected go to conditional formatting.  In conditional formatting, select new rule and then select "Use a formula to determine..."

In the formula bar try entering:

```
=A$1=TODAY()
```

Then select the format button and choose all the formatting changes you want to apply if its true.

This only works if the top address is stored in an Excel Date serial format.  Additionally I have assumed to the top row of your data that contains the date is row 1.  You will have to adjust the A$1 address to suit your data location.